# how to send this array as one embed message in discord.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js

I want to send this data as one embed message and I don't know how many of these we have.

I tried to do like **this :**

```
            let list = hk;
            var id = "";
            var username = "";
            var identifier = ""
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                id += list[i].id + '\n';
                username += list[i].user_name + '\n';
                identifier += list[i].identifier + '\n';

            }
                const pListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#03fc41')
                    .setTitle('Connected')
                    .setDescription(`Total : ${list.length}`)
                    .setThumbnail(config.logo)
                    .addFields({ name: 'ID', value: id, inline: true }, { name: 'Name', value: username, inline: true }, { name: 'Identifier', value: identifier, inline: true },

                    )
                    .setTimestamp(new Date())
                    .setFooter('Used by: ' + message.author.tag, `${config.SERVER_LOGO}`);

                message.channel.send(pListEmbed);
        });
```

but it sends several separate embed messages, each containing the data
and `hk` is this array that we don't know how many of the data we have

**array :**

```
        [
        {
      id: '46892319372',
      user_name: 'testerOne',
      identifier: '20202'
    }
]
[
    {
      id: '15243879678',
      user_name: 'testerTwo',
      identifier: '20201'
    }
]
[
    {
      id: '02857428679',
      user_name: 'testerThree',
      identifier: '20203'
    }
]
[
    {
      id: '65284759703',
      user_name: 'testerFour',
      identifier: '20204'
    }
]
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON array.

Comment: Yeah i put the hk to the [] and now it's a valid JSON array i think but whatever how can i send it as one message

Answer (score 0):

you can map the array into the fields like this:

**separate fields**

```js
.addFields(
  array.flatMap(user => [
    { name: 'ID', value: user.id, inline: true },
    { name: 'Name', value: user.user_name, inline: true },
    { name: 'Identifier', value: user.identifier, inline: true }
  ])
)
```

**single fields**

```js
.addFields(
  array.flatMap(user => [
    { name: 'User', value: `${id + username + identifier}`, inline: true },
  ])
)
```

**Why flatMap()?**

> flatMap() is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which is used to flatten the input array element into a new array. This method first of all map every element with the help of mapping function, then flattens the input array element into a new array.

Comment: you forgot to return the elements in the map method.

Comment: there is no problem with my answer.

Comment: Actually i got two error, ';' expected. And Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: i updated my answer and actually tested it to work this time.

Comment: Did you tested it with my array? Cause i tested it and it sends several embed messages too :(

Comment: do you mean you want each to be in a single field?

Comment: No i mean look we have 4 different id, user_name and identifier and it will send them as 4 different embed messages. I want to send it as one message like id = .. username = ... identifier = ... then go another field in same embed message and another id,username,identifier

Comment: is your `message.channel.send()` in a for loop or something? it shouldnt be doing that...

Comment: No it's not in a loop, it don't send same id,name... as 4 messages. It sends different id,name,identifiers as 4 embed messages actually it have to send it as one message with 4 fields

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.forEach`, that will loop over every single element and use the "addFields" method ->

```js
// .setThumbnail()..
list.forEach(user => pListEmbed.addFields(
  { name: 'ID', value: user.id, inline: true },
  { name: 'Name', value: user.user_name, inline: true },
  { name: 'Identifier', value: user.identifier, inline: true }
))

message.reply({ embeds : [pListEmbed] })
```

Comment: forEach loop is not very optimized in this situation

Comment: It sends several embed messages too